# In terms of design and when writing a library, when should I use a pointer as an argument, and when should I not?

Tags: pointers, go

Sorry if my question seems stupid. My background is in PHP, Ruby, Python, Lua and similar languages, and I have no understanding of pointers in real-life scenarios.

From what I've read on the Internet and what I've got as responses in a question I asked ([When is a pointer idiomatic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000292/when-is-a-pointer-idiomatic/35000714#35000714)), I have understood that:

- Pointers should be used when copying large data. Instead of getting the whole object hierarchy, receive its address and access it.
- Pointers have to be used when you have a function on a struct that modifies it.

So, pointers seem like a great thing: I should just always get them as function arguments because they are so lightweight, and it's okay if I somehow end up not needing to modify anything on the struct.

However, looking at that statement intuitively, I can feel that it sounds very creepy, and yet I don't know why.

So, as someone who is designing a struct and its related functions, or just functions, when should I receive a pointer? When should I receive a value, and why?

In other words, when should my `NewAuthor` method return `&Author{ ... }`, and when should it return `Author{ ... }`? When should my function get a pointer to an author as an argument, and when should it just get the value (a copy) of type `Author`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452323/go-performance-whats-the-difference-between-pointer-and-value-in-struct

Comment: In Go, I would only opt for a value over a pointer if I intend for instances of my type to be immutable. In my opinion pointers are almost always better and not just in Go.

Comment: I come from a similar background (Python, which does not have explicit pointers) and have settled on the same advice @evanmcdonnal gave. If You don't have an ***explicitly*** immutable class, you should pass by pointer.

Comment: And in addition, if your immutable values are large, *still* pass the pointer and only provide getters in the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's tradeoffs for both pointers and values.

Generally speaking, pointers will point to some other region of memory in the system.  Be it the stack of the function that wants to pass a pointer to a local variable or some place on the heap.

```
func A() {
    i := 25
    B(&i) // A sets up stack frame to call B,
          // it copies the address of i so B can look it up later.
    // At this point, i is equal to 30
}
func B(i *int){
     // Here, i points to A's stack frame.
     // For this to execute, I look at my variable "i", 
     //   see the memory address it points to, then look at that to get the value of 25.
     // That address may be on another page of memory, 
     // causing me to have to look it up from main memory (which is slow).
     println(10 + (*i)) 

     // Since I have the address to A's local variable, I can modify it.
     *i = 30
}
```

Pointers require me to de-reference them constantly whenever I was to see the data it points to.  Sometimes you don't care.  Other times it matters a lot.  It really depends on the application.

If that pointer has to be de-referenced a lot (ie: you pass in a number to use in a bunch of different calcs), then you keep paying the cost.

Compared to using values:

```
func A() {
    i := 25
    B(i) // A sets up the stack frame to call B, copying in the value 25
    // i is still 25, because A gave B a copy of the value, and not the address.
}
func B(i int){
     // Here, i is simply on the stack.  I don't have to do anything to use it.
     println(10 + i) 

     // Since i here is a value on B's stack, modifications are not visible outside B's scpe
     i = 30
}
```

Since there's nothing to dereference, it's basically free to use the local variable.

The down side of passing values happens if those values are large because copying data to the stack isn't free.

For an int it's a wash because pointers are "int" sized.  For a struct, or an array, you are copying all the data.

Also, large objects on the stack can make the stack extra big.  Go handles this well with stack re-allocation, but in high performance scenarios, it may be too much of an impact to performance.

There's a data safety aspect as well (can't modify something I pass by value), but I don't feel that is usually an issue in most code bases.

Basically, if your problem was already solvable by ruby, python or other language without value types, then these performance nuances don't super-matter.

In general, passing structs as pointers will usually do "the right thing" while learning the language.

For all other types, or things that you want to keep as read-only, pass values.

There are exceptions to that rule, but it's best that you learn those as needs arise rather than try to redefine your world all at once.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use pointers anywhere you want, sometimes you don't want to change your data. It may stand for abstract data, and you don't want to explicitly copy the data. Just pass by value and let compiler do its job.